# Need stack views in Razor that allows me to hide the views or the fields

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have several partial views that I need to stack them on my web page.

pv1  pv2

pv3  pv4

pv5  pv6

I also need to be able to hide any of them or even labels within each view.

I tried using a table but I cannot get them to show up right.

Here is an example of what I did:

```
<h2>AccountScreen</h2>

  <table>
    <tr>
      @Html.Partial("CustomerInfoPartialView")
    </tr>
    <tr>
      @Html.Partial("BalancePartialView")
    </tr>
  </table>
```

That didn't turn out anything like I was hoping for, it was a mess.

What should I use to stack my partial views and also be able to hide/show them programmatically?

Comment: Why not `<div>`s? I'm not sure I see a clear question here.

Comment: Agree that divs seem better, but if you're going to use a table, you need to make sure it's valid HTML.  If one of those is hidden, you're left with `<table><tr></tr>` (missing `td`).

Answer (score 1):

As people have said, you should use `<div>` elements. You should also give them unique identifiers and use jQuery to hide/show as necessary. If you have the criteria available at the time the model is rendered, it might be simpler to add a visible/hidden style as needed to each element.

```
@
{
    Html.Partial("CustomerInfoPartialView")
    ...
    Html.Partial("CustomerInfoPartialView")
}
```

Then in each partial:

```
@{
    var classToUse = (myVisibleCriteriaBool) ? "visibleClass" : "hiddenClass";
}
<div id="UniqueNamePartialView" class="stackableDivs @classToUse">
    Your html stuff here
</div>
```

As long as the class `stackableDivs` (I just made this up) includes a float style, they should stack appropriately. That would probably need to be adjusted depending on how you wanted them to stack, but it should still be a matter of css. If you don't know at the time the view is rendered, you could use jQuery to hide the individual elements:

```
$($('#UniqueNamePartialView").hide());
```

or

```
$($('#UniqueNamePartialView").show());
```

I would stay away from `toggle()` since it's [deprecated](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide/show them in C# within the View, all you have to do is to render them or not.

If you want to hide/show them in JavaScript, just put them inside a `div` and use `$("your_div").toggle();`